# conda build R packages to different library location

Tags: r, conda, conda-build

I'm following the instructions from https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-data-science in order to build a CRAN-available R package (e.g. synthpop).

```
conda skeleton cran synthpop
conda build r-synthpop
```

How can I change the default conda build sequence to install to a different library location, as I don't have permission to install to the default one?

```
* installing to library ‘/path/to/default/lib’
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/path/to/default/lib’
```

Also, I'm running conda build from within a virtual env.

Raised this as an issue here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1562

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was faced with this similar problem recently. After some researches, I wrote one passage about it

https://github.com/alfredzj/Documentations/blob/master/anaconda-set-up.md

I don't think changing location is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The --croot option allows installs to a specific location:

```
conda build --croot /path/to/somewhere/env r-synthpop/
```

In our case we had two R installs, and the configuration in .Rprofile listed a library location which had restricted write permissions. This location masked the path we gave via --croot. Once we edited .Rprofile we could run conda build with the desired path.